# raw input, global mouse hooks and interaction with windows

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, raw-input

So, I write program which processes signals from mice. I use mice like buttons for intellectual game (also know as Proteus, you can use wiki to know more about it). My company don't want to spend a lot of money that's why I have to use mice like buttons for this game :-)
 
I use RAW INPUT to get device name and to find out which of them was pressed by gamer. 
I have problem. When somebody clicks button, the button activates another window, clicks button and interacts with Windows:-) 
 
I know, that I can block this interaction with global hooks but I cannot get device name if i use it. 
 
I want to get device name and signal from mouse, but I don't want to this mouse interacts with Windows. Did anybody solve this problem?

Comment: did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: Yeah, I've solved this problem. I use left button of mouse like the button for gamers. I use it instead of push-buttons for Protmušis game :D